# a very strange question in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am doing this in mma v7.0:

`r[x_] := Rationalize[x, 0]; 
N[Nest[Sqrt, 10., 53] // r, 500]`

It gave me
`1.000000000000000222044604925031308084726333618164062500000000000000000`

However, if I go one step further
`N[Nest[Sqrt, 10., 54] // r, 500]`

I got all zeros. Does anybody know an explanation, or it is a bug?

Besides, looks like this way to produce more digits from the solution `Nest[Sqrt, 10., 53]` is not working very well. How to obtain more significant digits for this calculation?

Many thanks.

**Edit**

If I did `Nest[Sqrt, 10., 50]`, I still got a lot of significant digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
InputForm /@ NestList[Sqrt, 10., 54]
```

---

```
10.
3.1622776601683795
1.7782794100389228
1.333521432163324
1.1547819846894583
1.0746078283213176
1.036632928437698
1.018151721718182
1.0090350448414476
1.0045073642544626
1.002251148292913
1.00112494139988
1.0005623126022087
1.00028111678778
1.0001405485169472
1.0000702717894114
1.000035135277462
1.0000175674844227
1.0000087837036347
1.0000043918421733
1.0000021959186756
1.000001097958735
1.0000005489792168
1.0000002744895706
1.000000137244776
1.0000000686223856
1.000000034311192
1.0000000171555958
1.0000000085777978
1.0000000042888988
1.0000000021444493
1.0000000010722245
1.0000000005361123
1.0000000002680562
1.0000000001340281
1.000000000067014
1.000000000033507
1.0000000000167535
1.0000000000083769
1.0000000000041884
1.0000000000020943
1.0000000000010472
1.0000000000005236
1.0000000000002618
1.000000000000131
1.0000000000000655
1.0000000000000329
1.0000000000000164
1.0000000000000082
1.000000000000004
1.000000000000002
1.0000000000000009
1.0000000000000004
1.0000000000000002
1.
```

Throwing `N[x, 500]` on this is like trying to squeeze water from a rock.

---

The calculations above are done in machine precision, which is very fast.  If you are willing to give up speed, you can utilize [Mathematica's arbitrary precision arithmetic](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ArbitraryPrecisionNumbers.html) by specifying a non-machine precision on the input values.  The "backtick" can be used to do this (as in the example below) or you can use [`SetPrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SetPrecision.html) or [`SetAccuracy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SetAccuracy.html).  Here I will specify that the input is the number 10 up to 20 digits of precision.

```
NestList[Sqrt, 10`20, 54]
```

---

```
10.000000000000000000
3.1622776601683793320
1.77827941003892280123
.
.
.
1.00000000000000051127659728012947952
1.00000000000000025563829864006470708
1.000000000000000127819149320032345372
```

As you can see you do not need to use `InputForm` as Mathematica will automatically print arbitrary-precision numbers to as many places as it accurately can.

If you do use `InputForm` or `FullForm` you will see a backtick and then a number, which is the current precision of that number.

Comment: Wizard: +1, do you know some way to get even more digits than InputForm? Thanks.

Comment: @Qiang Li yes, you can kick on the arbitrary precision engine by specifying a non-machine precision on the input numbers.  I will edit to provide an example.

Comment: Wizard, I see. Forgot that I could use ```. :) Regarding my original question, I am still puzzled at why the answer was not correct after more times of application of the function `Sqrt`. Maybe it was because of `Rationalize` function? I cannot accept your answer for now, even though you solve my question in another direction. Many thanks.

Comment: @Qiang Li, what answer are you expecting?  I the Rationalized value of `1.` is simply `1`, the exact value.  Asking for 500 digits of One is simply one followed by 499 zeros.  Perhaps I don't understand the question.

Comment: Wizard, okay, i guess it is the approximation in Rationalize that caused the problem.

Answer (score 4):

You have no significant digits other than zeros if you do this 54 times. Hence rationalizing as you do (which simply preserves bit pattern) gives what you saw.

```
InputForm[n53 = Nest[Sqrt, 10., 53]]
```

Out[180]//InputForm=
1.0000000000000002

```
InputForm[n54 = Nest[Sqrt, 10., 54]]
```

Out[181]//InputForm=
1.

```
Rationalize[n53, 0]
```

4503599627370497/4503599627370496

```
Rationalize[n54, 0]
```

Out[183]= 1

For the curious: the issue is not loss of precision in the sense of degradation with iterations computation. Indeed, iterating these square roots actually increases precision. We can see this with bignum input.

```
InputForm[n54 = Nest[Sqrt, 10.`20, 54]]
```

Out[188]//InputForm=
1.0000000000000001278191493200323453724568038240908339267044`36.25561976585499

Here is the actual problem. When we use machine numbers then after 54 iterations there are no significant digits other than zeros in the resulting machine double. That is to say, our size restriction on the numbers is the cause.

The reason is not too mysterious. Call the resulting value 1+eps. Then we have (1+eps)^(2^54) equal (to close approximation) to 10. A second order expansion then shows eps must be smaller than machine epsilon.

```
InputForm[epsval =
```

First[Select[
    eps /. N[Solve[Sum[eps^j*Binomial[2^54, j], {j, 2}] == 9, eps]], 
    Head[#] === Real && # > 0 &]]]
Out[237]//InputForm=
1.864563472253985*^-16

```
$MachineEpsilon
```

Out[235]= 2.22045*10^-16

Daniel Lichtblau
Wolfram Research